# React SSR window is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog

Hello guys I'm trying to use dialog polyfill, to open modal window
But when I try to register it I get `window is not defined` cause I'm using SSR in React

Here is my Modal component

```
import dialogPolyfill from 'dialog-polyfill'

export const Modal = ({ children, style }) => {
  const { modalRef } = useDialog()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (modalRef.current && !modalRef.current.showModal) {
      if (!isServer) {
        dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(modalRef.current)
      }
    }
  }, [dialogRef])

  return (
    <>
      <dialog open ref={dialogRef} style={style}>
        {children}
      </dialog>
    </>
  )
}
```

Does anyone know how I can bypass it, I tried with this if statement

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(modalRef.current)
}
```

but its not working :/